# Stringbuffer access by index or range

Tags: flutter, dart, stringbuffer

TLDR: I am looking for a datastructure with the properties of a string buffer that I can access by index in dart.

Long version: I need the properties of Stringbuffer (very efficient at adding characters/bytes) but with the added capability of accessing characters/bytes at specific indices or ranges.
I am very surprised that something as simple as that does not seem to exist, neither in the dart core nor in custom libraries.

Fyi I am trying to build a piece table in dart. I do not think that simply calling `stringbuffer.toString().substring(start, end)` is an option, as this probably copies the whole string, which is the opposite of the efficiency I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: After playing around with the [typed library](https://pub.dev/packages/typed_data/install) and some custom data structures for a bit, it seems that a simple list of Strings is actually the fastest, assuming that I need half as many insertions as I need random read access.

Of course still open to any suggestions from anyone who knows more about dart, microbenchmarking, etc.

```
class IndexableStringBuffer {
  final List<String> _characters = List.empty(growable: true);

  int get length => _characters.length;

  void writeAll(String string) {
    _characters.addAll(string.characters);
  }

  String getRange(int start, int? end) {
    return _characters.sublist(start, end).join();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am very surprised that something as simple as that does not seem to exist, neither in the dart core nor in custom libraries.

I would not expect that to be something that many people need to do, so I am not surprised.

Here is a quick implementation to get you started.  The basic principle is to keep track of starting (and/or ending) indices of each string component.  When doing lookups, do a binary-search on those indices to find the relevant components. [`lowerBound`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/lowerBound.html) from [`package:collection`](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) is useful for this.

This implementation operates in terms of UTF-16 code units (which is what Dart's [`String`] class uses), but it should not be too hard to make it use `Runes`/code-points instead if you want.

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

/// Part of a [IndexableStringBuffer].
class _Part implements Comparable<_Part> {
  const _Part(this.startIndexCodeUnits, [this.string = '']);

  final String string;

  final int startIndexCodeUnits;

  int get endIndexCodeUnits => startIndexCodeUnits + length;
  int get length => string.length;

  @override
  String toString() => string;

  @override
  int compareTo(_Part other) =>
      endIndexCodeUnits.compareTo(other.endIndexCodeUnits);
}

/// Similar to [StringBuffer] but allows extracting a substring.
class IndexableStringBuffer {
  final _parts = <_Part>[];
  int _totalLengthCodeUnits = 0;

  IndexableStringBuffer();

  int get totalLengthCodeUnits => _totalLengthCodeUnits;

  /// Adds a new [String].
  void add(String string) {
    _parts.add(_Part(_totalLengthCodeUnits, string));
    _totalLengthCodeUnits += string.length;
  }

  /// Returns a substring in the range \[start, end), where [start] and
  /// [end] are indices in UTF-16 code units.
  String substring(int start, int end) {
    assert(start >= 0);
    assert(start <= totalLengthCodeUnits);
    assert(end >= 0);
    assert(end <= totalLengthCodeUnits);

    // Inclusive start and end indices of the relevant substrings from [_parts].
    var startPartIndex = lowerBound<_Part>(_parts, _Part(start));
    var endPartIndex = lowerBound<_Part>(_parts, _Part(end));

    if (startPartIndex == _parts.length) {
      return '';
    }

    var startPart = _parts[startPartIndex];
    var startOffset = start - startPart.startIndexCodeUnits;
    assert(startOffset >= 0);

    var substring = _parts.getRange(startPartIndex, endPartIndex + 1).join();
    return substring.substring(startOffset, startOffset + end - start);
  }
}

// And some quick tests to kick the tires:
void main() {
  var buffer = IndexableStringBuffer();
  print(buffer.substring(0, 0));
  
  buffer
    ..add('hello')
    ..add('world')
    ..add('goodbye')
    ..add('friend');

  print(buffer.substring(0, 3)); // hel
  print(buffer.substring(1, 4)); // ell
  print(buffer.substring(1, 5)); // ello
  print(buffer.substring(5, 7)); // wo
  print(buffer.substring(0, 10)); // helloworld
  print(buffer.substring(3, 9)); // loworl
  print(buffer.substring(10, 12)); // go
  print(buffer.substring(9, 12)); // dgo
  print(buffer.substring(0, 23)); // helloworldgoodbyefriend
  print(buffer.substring(0, 0)); //
  print(buffer.substring(23, 23)); //
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply! According to my [very basic benchmarking](https://gist.github.com/ChiIIBiII/6929958deb903fb4ba0a29c1055dfc0e) this buffer implementation seems to be about half as fast as the library implementation and about 75 times faster than simple string concatenation, so definitely usable.

It's unfortunate though that the library implementation apparently can not be extended easily.

Comment: I was surprised because it seems to me that implementing index acces would not add much complexity to any buffer, since it has to keep track of it's part's locations in memory and lengths anyway. But apparently you're right and it is not commonly used.